# what is the meaning of sentence containing Gamma like symbol

Tags: notation, computer-science

I am reading the following document (Allocating Objects) in the contacts of Stable Matching algorithms for Housing units:

[Allocating objects](https://web.stanford.edu/~niederle/HouseAllocation.pdf)

The document uses a gamma like symbol as shown in this image:

[image]

I can’t understand this gamma like symbol. Some body please tell me what is the name of this symbol and what does the point (3) mean in the above image in which this symbol is used?

Zulfi.

Comment: It's a common symbol for a general *partial order*, though based on point 3, here it is a *collection* of partial orders on $H$, one for each agent $a$.

Comment: Does it have any name? What is the difference when used with subscript 'a' followed by opening parenthesis, subscript 'a' with underscore followed by closing parenthesis and then with '=' followed by subscript 'a' within the parenthesis?

Comment: You can call them $R_a$, these are some ordering relations. The notation $(R_a)_{a\in A}$ means the *collection* of these $R_a$'s. Specifically, for houses $x,y$, the relation $x\, R_a\, y$ wants to mean that agent $a$ prefers $x$ to $y$.